# Processing async results with Arrow-kt and Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, async-await, either, arrow-kt

I have two async function calls to external systems returning Either<Exception, Something> and need to combine their results. Being a beginner in functional programming in Arrow-Kt, I am wondering which is the best way of accomplishing this task.
Below is the code, which I am currently using. It certainly works but does not really "feel" to be most straight forward. I am looking for a more "functional" style to get the result.
NB: the upfront usage of the successful List result is necessary.

```
suspend fun getAs(): Either<Exception, List<A>> = TODO()
suspend fun getBs(): Either<Exception, List<B>> = TODO()
suspend fun doSomethingWithA(listA: List<A>): Unit = TODO()

launch {
    val deferredA = async { getAs() }
    val deferredB = async { getBs() }

    either<Exception, List<A>> {
        val listOfAs = deferredA.await()
            .bimap(leftOperation = { e ->
                println("special message on error for A")
                e
            }, rightOperation = { listA ->
                doSomethingWithA(listA)
                listA
            })
            .bind()
        val listOfBs = deferredB.await().bind()

        listOfAs.filter { it.someId !in listOfBs.map { it.someProperty } }
    }
    .map { /* handle result */ }
    .handleError { /* handle error */ }

}
```

An alternative option would be to just use the `map{}` function like so

```
launch {
    val deferredA = async { getAs() }
    val deferredB = async { getBs() }

    deferredA.await()
        .bimap(leftOperation = { e ->
            println("special message on error for A")
            e
        }, rightOperation = { listA ->
            doSomethingWithA(listA)
            deferredB.await().map { listB ->
                listA.filter { a -> a.someId !in listB.map { it.someProperty } }
            }
        })
        .map { /* handle result */ }
        .handleError { /* handle error */ }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is to combine `either { }` with `parZip`.
`either { }` allows you to extract `A` from `Either<E, A>`, and `parZip` is a utility function for running `suspend` function in parallel.

```kotlin
suspend fun getAs(): Either<Exception, List<A>> = TODO()
suspend fun getBs(): Either<Exception, List<B>> = TODO()
suspend fun doSomethingWithA(listA: List<A>): Unit = TODO()

either {
  val list = parZip(
    {
       getAs()
         .mapLeft { e -> println("special message on error for A"); e }
         .bind()
    },
    { getBs().bind() },
    { aas, bbs ->
      aas.filter { a -> a.someId !in bbs.map { it.someProperty }
    }
  )

  /* Work with list and return value to `either { } */
}.handleError { /* handle error */ }
```

Here `bind()` extracts `A` from `Either<E, A>`. We do this inside `parZip` such that whenever a `Left` gets encountered it short-circuits the `either { }` block and by doing so, it also cancels the still running tasks in `parZip`.

Such that if `getAs()` returns immediately with `Left` then it becomes the output value of `either { }` and `getBs()` gets cancelled.

Answer (score 3):

I was about to post a very similar answer. Note that `getAs` and `getBs` **are not really sequential**, since `getBs` does not need the result of `getAs` to be executed. They only happen to need to combine results in the end. In other words: we can parallelize

Here you have some additional things I'd do on top of what Simon suggested. (I'll replace A's and B's in this example by `NetworkUser` and `DbUser` to try to give it some semantics, since otherwise those "id" properties on the filter will not work.

**Capture errors and map them to strongly type domain errors on each of those effectful functions.**

This will help to both remove burden from the rest of the program, and on top of it provide a safer domain error hierarchy that we can perform exhaustive evaluation on when required.

```kotlin
suspend fun <A> getUsersFromNetwork(): Either<DomainError, List<NetworkUser>> =
 Either.catch { fetchUsers() }
   .mapLeft { exception ->
     println("special message on error for A")
     exception.toDomain()
   }
```

**Make the doSomething function return Either in case it can also fail.**

This is a function you said it's required right after the initial get, which means flatMap or bind (they're equivalent). If we lift it into `Either` that'll ensure error short-circuiting takes place as expected, so this operation never runs in the initial one didn't succeed.

I suggest doing this because I suspect this operation you have here is also an effect in your code as a consequence of the first operation, probably something to store the result of the first operation in a local cache or another type of effect that is simply consuming that result.

```kotlin
suspend fun doSomethingWithNetworkUsers(listA: List<NetworkUser>): Either<DomainError, Unit> = TODO()
```

So our functions we'll rely on from the composed one can look like this:

```kotlin
suspend fun getUsersFromNetwork(): Either<DomainError, List<NetworkUser>> = TODO()
suspend fun getUsersFromDb(): Either<DomainError, List<DbUser>> = TODO()
suspend fun doSomethingWithNetworkUsers(listA: List<NetworkUser>): Either<DomainError, Unit> = TODO()
```

And the program:

```kotlin
fun CoroutineScope.program() {
  launch {
    either {
      parZip(
        {
          val networkUsers = getUsersFromNetwork().bind()
          doSomethingWithNetworkUsers(networkUsers).bind()
          networkUsers
        },
        { getUsersFromDb().bind() }
      ) { networkUsers, dbUsers ->
        networkUsers.filter { networkUser ->
          networkUser.id !in dbUsers.map { dbUser -> dbUser.id }
        }
      }
    }
    .map { /* do something with the overall result */ }
    .handleError { /* can recover from errors here */ }
    // Alternatively:
    // .fold(ifLeft = {}, ifRight = {}) for handling both sides.
  }
}
```

By doing the first operation as a composed one with binds first, like in the following snippet extracted from the one above, we make sure both operations are done before the parZip lambda to combine results takes place.

```kotlin
val networkUsers = getUsersFromNetwork().bind()
doSomethingWithNetworkUsers(networkUsers).bind()
networkUsers
```

Comment: From the Left part of the Either (the exceptions)  I really only use (in this case) the exception message. So it could indeed be transformed into a String - creating a domain error type would be a little overkill for this particular use case. The DoSomethingWithA() may have side effects and fail, thus the return type of Either is a good idea, a failure must not lead to short circuiting the evaluation of B. The side effect is an update of the UI, which I didn't mention in the first place.